# I need a better way to draw letters using SVG path

Tags: svg

I am trying to convert my website logo into SVG paths. I have been doing this for 2 days, I have read every article or tutorial to use SVG but I haven't seen one that tells you how to create a simple letter.

Please, I am racking my brains here.

here is what I have:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="7" d="M36 40,32,33 C-4,24 -1,98 37,54 l0,-5 -21,0"></path>
```

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve.
[image]
can you please help me how can I achieve this kind of lettering using SVG paths. As you can see, my artwork is not even close. I'm desperate.

Comment: There are several software packages that let you write text with your preferred font, can then convert it into a path and export it as SVG. Sketch, Illustrator, Inkscape etc.

Comment: Illustrator will allow you to transform text to path:  Select: Type > Create Outlines from the menu

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've done it! I used adobe illustrator to export the SVG with path!

and here is my end result!

```
<svg width="114" height="17"><path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="0.2" d="M12,2.08a6.39,6.39,0,0,1,2.33,3.7H11.83a4.18,4.18,0,0,0-1.6-2A4.54,4.54,0,0,0,7.61,3a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-2.5.68A4.62,4.62,0,0,0,3.39,5.65a6.42,6.42,0,0,0-.62,2.93,6.76,6.76,0,0,0,.63,3,4.42,4.42,0,0,0,1.78,1.94,5.13,5.13,0,0,0,2.66.67A4.6,4.6,0,0,0,11,13a5.17,5.17,0,0,0,1.61-3.28H7.17V7.92h7.48v2.39a7.62,7.62,0,0,1-1.17,3.1,6.8,6.8,0,0,1-2.42,2.22,7.1,7.1,0,0,1-3.45.83,7.25,7.25,0,0,1-3.83-1,6.82,6.82,0,0,1-2.57-2.8A8.82,8.82,0,0,1,.3,8.58,8.82,8.82,0,0,1,1.21,4.5,6.62,6.62,0,0,1,3.77,1.72a7.19,7.19,0,0,1,3.82-1A7,7,0,0,1,12,2.08Zm9.14,2.66a4.64,4.64,0,0,1,2.53-.69V6.76H23a3.86,3.86,0,0,0-2.54.8,3.26,3.26,0,0,0-1,2.64v6.11h-2.4V4.25h2.4V6.61A4.63,4.63,0,0,1,21.16,4.74Zm11.67.16a4.33,4.33,0,0,1,1.58,2.15V4.25h2.4V16.31h-2.4v-2.8a4.3,4.3,0,0,1-1.58,2.14,4.45,4.45,0,0,1-2.69.81,4.88,4.88,0,0,1-4.58-2.89,7.5,7.5,0,0,1-.67-3.3A7.52,7.52,0,0,1,25.56,7a4.92,4.92,0,0,1,4.58-2.89A4.45,4.45,0,0,1,32.83,4.9ZM28.31,7.34a4.22,4.22,0,0,0-1,2.93,4.2,4.2,0,0,0,1,2.92,3.28,3.28,0,0,0,2.56,1.06,3.34,3.34,0,0,0,1.81-.49A3.42,3.42,0,0,0,34,12.37a4.51,4.51,0,0,0,.46-2.1A4.5,4.5,0,0,0,34,8.18a3.34,3.34,0,0,0-3.08-1.9A3.32,3.32,0,0,0,28.31,7.34ZM49.44,5.41a5.6,5.6,0,0,1,1.22,3.87v7h-2.4V9.54A3.56,3.56,0,0,0,47.45,7a2.8,2.8,0,0,0-2.19-.89A3,3,0,0,0,43,7.1a4,4,0,0,0-.87,2.79v6.42H39.7V4.25h2.4V6.9a4.05,4.05,0,0,1,1.56-2.11,4.45,4.45,0,0,1,2.53-.74A4.16,4.16,0,0,1,49.44,5.41ZM60.81,4.9a4.18,4.18,0,0,1,1.56,2.15V.11H64.8v16.2H62.37v-2.8a4.15,4.15,0,0,1-1.56,2.14,4.45,4.45,0,0,1-2.69.81,4.88,4.88,0,0,1-4.58-2.89,7.5,7.5,0,0,1-.67-3.3A7.52,7.52,0,0,1,53.54,7a4.92,4.92,0,0,1,4.58-2.89A4.45,4.45,0,0,1,60.81,4.9ZM56.29,7.34a4.22,4.22,0,0,0-1,2.93,4.2,4.2,0,0,0,1,2.92,3.28,3.28,0,0,0,2.56,1.06,3.4,3.4,0,0,0,1.82-.49,3.47,3.47,0,0,0,1.26-1.39,4.51,4.51,0,0,0,.46-2.1,4.5,4.5,0,0,0-.46-2.09,3.31,3.31,0,0,0-3.08-1.9A3.32,3.32,0,0,0,56.29,7.34ZM84,4.25,80.72,16.31H78.07L75.2,7l-2.9,9.33H69.66L66.44,4.25h2.42L71.07,14,74,4.25h2.53L79.46,14l2.21-9.76Zm12.34,6.52H87.36a3.87,3.87,0,0,0,1,2.76,3.18,3.18,0,0,0,2.3.9,3.26,3.26,0,0,0,2-.64,2.57,2.57,0,0,0,1-1.68h2.57a5.17,5.17,0,0,1-1,2.25,5,5,0,0,1-1.91,1.54,6.43,6.43,0,0,1-5.62-.18,5.21,5.21,0,0,1-2-2.15,7,7,0,0,1-.74-3.3A7,7,0,0,1,85.74,7a5.18,5.18,0,0,1,2-2.14,6.35,6.35,0,0,1,6,0,5,5,0,0,1,2,2,5.93,5.93,0,0,1,.69,2.86A5.63,5.63,0,0,1,96.29,10.77ZM93.57,7.65a2.8,2.8,0,0,0-1.18-1.18,3.51,3.51,0,0,0-1.64-.39,3.31,3.31,0,0,0-2.36.9,3.77,3.77,0,0,0-1,2.65H94A4,4,0,0,0,93.57,7.65Zm14.49-2.81A5,5,0,0,1,109.93,7a7.52,7.52,0,0,1,.67,3.29,7.5,7.5,0,0,1-.67,3.3,4.88,4.88,0,0,1-4.57,2.89,4.46,4.46,0,0,1-2.7-.81,4.15,4.15,0,0,1-1.56-2.14v2.8H98.7V.11h2.4V7.05a4.18,4.18,0,0,1,1.56-2.15,4.46,4.46,0,0,1,2.7-.81A4.94,4.94,0,0,1,108.06,4.84Zm-5.25,1.93a3.42,3.42,0,0,0-1.27,1.41,4.5,4.5,0,0,0-.46,2.09,4.51,4.51,0,0,0,.46,2.1,3.42,3.42,0,0,0,1.27,1.39,3.34,3.34,0,0,0,1.81.49,3.31,3.31,0,0,0,2.57-1.06,4.2,4.2,0,0,0,1-2.92,4.23,4.23,0,0,0-1-2.92,3.31,3.31,0,0,0-2.57-1.07A3.43,3.43,0,0,0,102.81,6.77Z"/></svg>
```

Beautiful!

Comment: Could you please send me the SVG path for the word  RiskModeller for website name